# Bug: I Can't Post Comments

Tags: support, status-declined, comments

I can't post comments, whether they're on my own posts or another user's posts. When I try press the 'Add comment' button, nothing happens. I'm also not using any script blocking browser plugins like NoSpace. I meet the reputation requirements. Why is this happening?
Is it something to do with the web browser I use? I use the Amazon Kindle Experimental Web Browser. Thanks!

Comment: Things not working in unsupported browsers is not a bug, which is why I removed the tag. There's no need to bother the dev team with things like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser you are using is not in the [list of supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), or even in the list of browsers that are not officially supported but seem to work anyway. As this seems to be a client-side issue, it is likely that there is simply some incompatibility between Stack Exchange's code and your browser.

Comment: Yeah, I think "experimental" might be an important word in that browser's name.

Answer (score 4):

We do not support browsers in beta/alpha or experimental states.

Please use one of the [supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).